# Divs absolute into responsive img

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a responsive/height image, I want to put absolute elements into img, one by corner but I don't know how to do it, because image size will be dynamic.

Code:

```css
#contenedorimagen {
  width: 100%;
  background: #000;
}
#imagen {
  position: relative;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 90vh;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-align: center;
}
#i {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  max-height: 100%;
}
#imagen #c {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  color: #fff;
}
#imagen #h {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  color: #fff;
}
#imagen #pm {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div id="contenedorimagen">
  <div id="imagen">
    <div id="c">0</div>
    <div id="h">0</div>
    <div id="pm">0</div>
    <img id="i" src="https://i.imgur.com/kLkrgKO.jpg" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Thanks

Example image
[firefox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6dxkV.png)

Answer (score 0):

You need to give `max-width` to image container

```css
#contenedorimagen {
    width: 100%;
    background: #000;
}

#imagen {
    position: relative;
    width: 100vw;
    height: 90vh;
    max-width: 100%;
    vertical-align: middle;
    text-align: center;
}

#i {
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    max-height: 100%;
}

#imagen #c {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    color: #fff;
}

#imagen #h {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    color: #fff;
}

#imagen #pm {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div id="contenedorimagen">
    <div id="imagen">
        <div id="c">0</div>
        <div id="h">0</div>
        <div id="pm">0</div>
        <img id="i" src="https://i.imgur.com/kLkrgKO.jpg" />
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks Noopur, i need absolute divs into image, not into #imagen div. Thank you very much.

Comment: They are above image, why it is not working for you, because, your image is going outside of the container, and hence when you set `right:0` to your absolute div, you can't see it in black #contenedorimagen div. To fix it you need to fit image inside #contenedorimagen div

Comment: Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can adapt this example for your exact needs:

```css
#contenedorimagen {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

#contenedorimagen #i {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  display: block;
}

#contenedorimagen div {
  background: #000;
  padding: 15px;
  color: #fff;
}

#c {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

#h {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
}

#pm {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="contenedorimagen">
  <div id="c">0</div>
  <div id="h">0</div>
  <div id="pm">0</div>
  <img id="i" src="https://i.imgur.com/kLkrgKO.jpg" />
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you dom_ahdigital. If i apply max-height 100% to #i and height: 90vh to #contenedorimagen to height responsive image...   https://jsfiddle.net/xb5dws9o/